# change href in many a links with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change urls I get back from google search, because sometimes google likes to phone home about my browsing habbits (*sigh* that used to be yahoo's evil). :S I am getting an error from what seems to be valid jquery, was wondering what the fix is?

The error code is (cryptic, because I'm in chrome v8): 
`TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined`

Here's the source:

```
$("a[href^='http://www.google.com/url'], a[href^='www.google.com/url'], a[href^='/url?'], a[href^='url?']").each(
function(a) { 
    var url = "";
    $(a).attr("href").split("&").each(function (part) {
        if (part.match(/^url\=/)) {
            url = unescape( (part.split("=",2))[1] );
        }
    });
    $(a).attr("href", url);
});
```

I've verified that the error I am getting is on the first split, not the one on the **part** parameter.

Comment: Tried using `$(this)` not `$(a)` in `function(a)` that you call for each `a` element in that string?

Comment: You are not supposed to use the `.each()` method on anything but a jQuery object. And the array returned by `split()` is no such object. Use `$.each($(a).attr('href').split('&'), function(i, part) { ... });` instead.

Comment: @ThiefMaster — yea have to use `for ... splits.length` to iterate :P forgot that too

Comment: `$.each` is fine and nicer (imo). just don't confuse `$().each` with `$.each`. see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ and http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of the callback function you're using is actually the index of the array used for the `each()`.  Try this instead:

```
$("a[href^='http://www.google.com/url'], a[href^='www.google.com/url'], a[href^='/url?'], a[href^='url?']").each(
function() { 
    var url = "";
    $(this).attr("href").split("&").each(function (part) {
        if (part.match(/^url\=/)) {
            url = unescape( (part.split("=",2))[1] );
        }
    });
    $(this).attr("href", url);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to the `each` callback (your `a`) is an **index**, not the element.

Instead of `each`, you should pass a callback to `attr`:

```
$("a[...]").attr("href", function(index, oldValue) {
    return something;
});
```

Comment: I'd vote you up if I had rep :D it is the index, and I am inside an object  method so I can use **this** without any parameter setting.